# Using ildasm to detect markup differences between WPF assemblies

Tags: wpf, ildasm

I use ildasm to determine changes/differences between built assemblies.  This works well, but when I try and get it to detect changes in Xaml for (WPF projects), I cannot find any differences - after changes are made to the projects markup.

Any ideas?  Am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes XAML files are not compiled to IL and IL stays intact. That's why you don't notice any difference.

XAML files are compiled to BAML(Binary Application Markup Language) and stored as a embedded resource in the assembly itself. For comparing BAML, you need to use [BAML Reader](http://www.wpftutorial.net/baml.html).

[More on BAML](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2007/05/25/compiled-xaml-baml-not-il/)